# How do I trick the devil?

Tags: reigns

In Reigns, sooner or later you get task to "trick the devil".

How do you do that?

If you ask the witch for a way to trick the devil, she just gives you a bunch of year numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Those are important, on your timeline at those years there are alchemical symbols, screenshot those and do them in order next time you enter the pungeon, if the king is looking away from the symbol, use the other option. It's also important to have the strawberries, give them to the skeleton you eventually encounter and he'll become your friend and you have to use your death wish on him, spoiler alert, he can't kill him.

Comment: Where do you get strawberries, haven't encountered any?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to get the strawberry and it's a little tricky to figure out. See my [Q&A on that topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295730/how-do-i-get-a-strawberry). Otherwise, the best walkthrough I've found is [here on AppUnwrapper](http://www.appunwrapper.com/2016/08/12/reigns-walkthrough-guide-how-to-trick-the-devil/).

The trick is to get this setup right so that when you're cursed by the devil (next person you say "Yes" to dies), you say "Yes" to a character that cannot be killed.

> For example, Kloc the skeleton.